# Is there any definition of canon for Lost in Space?

Tags: canon, lost-in-space

A number of TV and movie series in the science fiction and fantasy genres have specified canon.  This tells us what is absolutely true in that world/universe and what may be legends or could be true but is unproven, and what is simply not an official part of that universe.

Is there any determination for *Lost in Space* what is canon?  Naturally the original series would be canon.  What about the comic books?  Is *Lost in Space Forever* considered canon or just a fun follow-up?

If there is a rule for what is and isn't canon, where did that rule come from and, if there isn't, who would have the authority to state, now, since both Irwin Allen and his wife are dead?  Would Bill Mumy, for example, who has been quite active in conventions and with other projects, have the authority to state what is and isn't canon at this point?

Comment: There is no canon, everything that could happen has happened somewhere within the multi-verse:D

Comment: @revenant: Just because a series is done does not mean there is no canon or issue with canon.

Comment: Which comic books are  you talking about?  The Space Family Robinson Lost in Space comic books are a totally separate series started years before the TV series.   The Space Family Robinson Lost in Space comic Books are not in canon with the Lost in Space TV show and vice versa.   I have read that there have been comic books based on the Lost in Space TV show and movie and the question of canon is relevant to them.

Answer (score 4):

Whoever owns the rights to Lost in Space has the power to determine what is canon. Look at what happened with Star Wars: once Disney bought the rights and proceeded with The Force Awakens, that rendered all the 'expanded universe' books non-canon. Even before that, Lucas himself contradicted some aspects of the EU with his prequels and Clone Wars series, making those aspects non-canonical as well. And even before that, he contradicted the novelization of A New Hope that he himself officially wrote! Certainly Mumy has no authority whatsoever - an actor (even a formerly cute little one) is just that: an actor, someone payed to play a part.

Comment: If the rights owners were to step forward and do something like define canon and do more than just syndicate the show, I would agree, but considering that there is a reboot in the works, it's very likely the owners (which seem to be either CBS or Fox) have no interest in dealing with such issues for the original series.  That would basically make it an orphan series and that would leave it up in the air, as it seems to be now.

Comment: There have been several attempts at a reboot over the years. I'll wait and see if this one makes it to air.

Comment: @JohnSensebe: Yes, there was the movie in the 1990s and a series pilot, but at this point Netflix has committed to an order of 10 episodes of a new reboot that will be released in 2018.